# Convert double field into string field without adding a field in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How can I convert a double field into a string field without adding a field in ArcGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We're a bit different than other help forums, in that we require you to make an effort to solve the task, then report the problem you have encountered. A single-sentence post is unlikely to contain enough detail to frame a problem. This post is unclear as to your goal; if you really want to alter a table to change an existing type without changing anything else, your task is impossible. If you are willing to create a new feature class, there are probably a half-dozen ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Mark answer as solution. Thanks is not enough

Answer (score 2):

As @BERA shared that you can't convert the data type without adding a new field, and the workflow you can follow is by creating a new field(string) and populating the records into it using the field calculator.

But, here is the trick, if you do not want to add a new field:

I'm not sure of the application you are working but the workflow can be used in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro.

Use the [Feature Class to Feature Class(Geoprocessing) conversion tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm).

[image]

**Feature Class to Feature Class GP tool:**

[image]

**Properties:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**The same goes for Pro:**
[image]

**Note: This workflow will create a new Feature Class.**

A help document for reference is shared below that uses field calculator for the objectives:

- [How To: Convert a string field to a numeric field](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000002287)